# xcode 6, resize inputAccessoryView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8

since new Xcode 6 came, I struggle with some problem. I can't resize the frame of inputAccessoryView.
I use custom inputAccessoryView  (resizable) for `UITextField`, which has as a subview `UITextview`. To resize content, I used to change the frame of accessoryView, and it worked. Now it has always the same init size.
Everything works perfect on *previous iOS 7*.

Comment: none of us had a problem with inputAccessoryView in new iOS

Comment: try set UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight to your accessory view.

Answer (score 0):

frist, get inputAccessoryView and set nil

```
UIView *inputAccessoryView = yourTextView.inputAccessoryView;
yourTextView.inputAccessoryView = nil;
[yourTextView reloadInputViews];
```

then set frame and layout

```
inputAccessoryView.frame = XXX
[inputAccessoryView setNeedsLayout];
[inputAccessoryView layoutIfNeeded];
```

last set new inputAccessoryView and reload

```
yourTextView.inputAccessoryView = inputAccessoryView;
[yourTextView reloadInputViews];
```